# If I modify elastic beanstalk stack and enable cross zone load balancing in elastic beanstalk then my application will get downtime or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently, My EC2 instances are in single availability zone in elastic beanstalk and I want to modify the elastic beanstalk stack and wants to enable cross-zone load balancing. but I am not sure is there face any application downtime if modify the stack? Or I can enable cross-zone load balancing on serving stack?